# How to create an Generic Interface with two methods with the same name but different signature?

Tags: c#, .net

I receive this error when trying to create a Generic Interface which have two method with same name but different signature.
Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

> Type 'XXX.Interfaces.IRepository' already defines a member called 'Delete' with the same parameter types

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Comment: The signature of the methods Delete are the same. They are both void and they take as an argument an object of the same type, T. Have you missed anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods don't have different signatures. The **names** of your method-parameters do not matter, only the **type**.

How are you going to specify in you calling code which method it is you want to call?

Is your `id` also of type `T`, or should it be of type `int`?

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T> {
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

They have the same signature (the parameter type is the important thing, not the parameter name).

If all your entities has an ID identity field, you probably want to change one of your delete method to

```
void Delete(int id);//or another type, if that's a GUID, a string...
```

But to be able to implement that delete function in a "generic environment", you'll probably need to have all your entities implementing an interface (they may inherit from a common base abstract class implementing that interface, if you wanna avoid writing too much code).

That'll be needed if you have a base Repository abstract class, with public and /or abstract and / or virtual methods (guess you have, assuming you don't wanna absolutely implement `Delete(int id)` for all your entities).

```
public interface IHasId {
  int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and add a constraint

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T> where T : class, IHasId
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter names don't count towards the signature.

If I called `repository.Delete(5)`, how would you know which method to run?

You may want to rename them. E.g., `DeleteById(T id)` and `DeleteEntity(T entity)`.

Answer (score 2):

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method and the
>   type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal
>   parameters, considered in the order left to right.

Copied from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So your `Delete(T)` method has the same signature for both methods. You could change your signatures to this (or also put `id` as `int`/`long`):

```
void Delete(object id);
void Delete(T entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to introduce another type parameter as `contravariant` to reflect this as different signature, say `X`

```
public interface IRepository<T, in X> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(X id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T id);
    void Delete(T entity) where T : <EntityType>;
    void Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two method(Delete) with the same signature. You should remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryReadOnly<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Why would you pass a T in to delete by ID? A T would be the entity type